# How can I get ffmpeg to convert a .mov to a .gif?

Tags: conversion, ffmpeg, gif

I'm trying to convert a .mov to a .gif and I'm not having success.

Here's the error:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt rgb24 -i yesbuddy.mov output.gif
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 17:47:34 with clang 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.11.1 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Option pixel_format not found.
```

If I leave out the -pix_fmt rgb24 part it complains. Thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: FYI, There is an excellent solution for high quality conversions given [here](http://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality/556031#556031).

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The order of command line arguments matters. This command line should work but will generate a giant file:

```
ffmpeg -i yesbuddy.mov -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif
```

Note that you probably want to reduce the frame rate and size when you convert, as well as specify a start time and duration. You probably do not want to convert the entire file at its original resolution and frame rate.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.000 -i yesbuddy.mov -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -s 320x240 -t 00:00:10.000 output.gif
```

The file size will still be huge. You may be able to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)'s GIF optimizer to reduce the size:

```
convert -layers Optimize output.gif output_optimized.gif
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks :) GIF is a crazy format... the original .mov was 250k, the converted .gif from ffmpeg was 8mb, and the `convert`-optimized version was an astounding 10k! Impressive!

Comment: ffmpeg complains about the pixel format, and switches from rgb24 to pal8; should the command in the answer be updated?

Comment: Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'gif'

Comment: @Andy auto-fixed to rgb8 in my version of ffmpeg.

Comment: how to do in Android?

Comment: My macbook is high cpu usage when run `convert -layers Optimize output.gif output_optimized.gif`

Answer (score 26):

After converting:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 input.gif
```

Try optimize frames:

```
convert input.gif -verbose -coalesce -layers OptimizeFrame input_optframe.gif
```

And use `gifsicle` to make final optimization:

```
gifsicle -O2 input_optframe.gif -o optimized.gif
```

Got 6.8mb GIF from 12.2mb video with almost the same quality!

Comment: Mind explaining how these steps work and what they are doing?

Comment: For me quality was horrible. https://superuser.com/a/1061409/376651 had a great results, at cost of a bit larger file

Answer (score 18):

```
ffmpeg -i <input source> -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=12,scale=<width>:-1,split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" <output file>
```

In this command there are 3 tokens you need to plug in. The `<input source>` will be something like `your-recording.mov`, the `<width>` should be the width you want the final gif to be, and `<output file>` will be something like `recording.gif`.

This command breaks down to mean:

- `filter_complex` we're going to be chaining some filters together
- `[0:v] fps=12` take the first video stream in the container at 12 frames per second
- `scale=1024:-1` resize to width of 1024 and keep aspect ratio for the height
- `split [a][b]` take the current stream and split it into two (basically clone it)
- `;` new filter incoming
- `[a] palettegen [p]` take the "a" stream and generate a color palette called "p"
- `;` new filter incoming
- `[b][p] paletteuse` take the "b" stream and apply "p" color palette

The color palette stuff isn't always necessary for screen recordings, but is definitely required to have better colors for recorded video.

You can also plug in `-ss 00:00:00.000` and `-t 00:00:00.000` as needed if you are going to be clipping it as well.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you :).

Answer (score 11):

I made a tool that bundles FFmpeg, ImageMagick and giflossy into a single easy to use command line program that you can install in one line: [Abandonware: gifify](https://github.com/vvo/gifify)

I recommend anyone willing to turn videos => GIF to use it instead of trying to spend a lot of time browsing 3 documentation websites to understand how to resize the GIF or change the start/end time.

Comment: And if you have Docker running on your machine, just do an alias like so: ```alias gifify='docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/data maxogden/gifify'``` then use it ```gifify screencast.mkv -o screencast.gif --resize 800:-1```

Comment: "I am no more using this project or providing any support to it, if you want to maintain it, ping me"

Comment: Still works great—just ran `docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/data maxogden/gifify my.mov -o my.gif --speed 1.5 --resize 1000:-1 --colors 255 --fps 6`

Answer (score 7):

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm - | convert -delay 2 -loop 0 -layers Optimize - gif:- | gifsicle -d 3 -O3 -o optimized.gif
```

first use ffmpeg to convert mp4 file to images via pipe
then use imagemagick to compress it to gif
at last optimized it with gifsicle

I don't know why using gifscicle directly won't work.

or you can make the gif smaller by this

```
convert -dither none -matte -depth 8 -deconstruct -layers optimizePlus -colors 32 in.gif out.gif
```