# Utility for converting wmv (or avi) to animated gif

Tags: windows, video, software-rec, images, video-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get ffmpeg to convert a .mov to a .gif?](https://superuser.com/questions/436056/how-can-i-get-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-mov-to-a-gif)

I'm looking for any console utility which can convert principally wmv files (or avi) to animated gif. Preferably the program would be a console application, because I'm going to call it within a C# or C++ program.

Note, it will be used on Windows only.

Comment: FFmpeg will read almost anything, so whether it's MOV or WMV doesn't matter. Please note that [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) hosts FFmpeg builds for Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FFmpeg can do this in Unix and Windows. You can download FFmpeg for Windows [from here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

In the most simple case, the conversion would work as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv output.gif
```

Comment: Do you exactly mean it can convert video to animated(!) gif ?

Comment: That is what it claims it can do. See for example this website: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

Comment: Hm, it converts avi (not wmv) to animated gif.

Comment: Are you sure (http://roundup.libav.org/issue1159)? What about first converting wmv to avi (using ffmpeg's -sameq parameter) and then to animated gif?

Comment: It's not good I think. It doesn't allow to convert wmv to animated gif directly, right?

Comment: M0sthated, the `sameq` parameter does not mean "same quality" and doesn't help preserving the quality when converting from WMV to AVI. The OP needs to specify the bitrate or quality factor for MPEG-4 accordingly.

Comment: I found that converting it to AVI first and then running this command, results in a much better quality gif. From WMV to GIF was almost unwatchable. Luckily, converting to AVI first, is exactly the same command with the file extensions switched around accordingly