# Could not find codec parameters in ffmpeg in Windows

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, video-conversion

While trying to convert wmv to animated gif using ffmpeg in Windows 7, I ran into an issue.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\>ffmpeg -i test.wmv test.gif
ffmpeg version N-39877-g4fa706a Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 16 2012 14:57:12 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-ru
ntime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass
 --enable-libcelt --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable
-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libope
njpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libth
eora --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-
libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --e
nable-zlib
  libavutil      51. 46.100 / 51. 46.100
  libavcodec     54. 14.101 / 54. 14.101
  libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 70.100 /  2. 70.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[asf @ 0000000001f3ead0] Could not find codec parameters (Video: none (MTS2 / 0x
3253544D), 800x400, 30000 kb/s)
test.wmv: could not find codec parameters
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you please download the latest static build for Windows from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and try again? Is there any way you could supply the original source file for us to download? Can you successfully convert other videos, e.g. with a different container like MP4 or MOV? Am I correct assuming these videos were created with Microsoft Expression Encoder?

Comment: Now it's working good. But it creates a very big animated gif. I need ffmpeg to compress it while it converts. What are the parameters should I use to reach it?

Comment: Depends on the dimension you want to scale. Do you want to keep the 800x400 size? If not, change it like `ffmpeg -i test.wmv … -s:v 400x200 out.gif`. Look at the answer you should have already seen for compression options: http://superuser.com/a/436109/48078

Answer (score 4):

The message seems like a parsing error. Your FFmpeg version however is several months old. The project is continually evolving. and with possible bugs like this, always try and use the latest version of FFmpeg.

- For Windows you must compile yourself e.g. with the [media autobuild suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite)
- On OS X, FFmpeg is easily installed through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) via `brew install ffmpeg`
- For Linux, you can compile it from source or use the static builds available at http://ffmpeg.org/download.html, or also install via Homebrew

Chances are bugs have already been fixed in the current Git head or the latest release.